# Применяется ли на практике пустое наследование?

Tags: java, ооп, наследование

Есть класс `User`. От него наследуется класс `Friend` и больше ничего в нем нет, то есть:

```
public class Friend extends User {

}
```

Я решил, что так "красивее", в частности, когда метод `getFriends` возвращает не `List<User>`, а `List<Friend>`. Применяется ли такой подход на практике?

Хотелось бы также узнать применяется ли это в моделях, в частности. То есть, в классах, где лежат данные и их геттеры/сеттеры

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Да, когда это необходимо, например в исключениях:

```
class MathException extends Exception{}
class OverflowException extends MathException{}
class DivByZeroException extends MathException{}
```

или где активно используется `reflection`.

Comment: Точно, спасибо) Видел много раз такое

Answer (score 11):

Применяется. В тех случаях когда тип несет какую-то особенную смысловую нагрузку - коллеги приводили случай типизированного `Exception` - это один из таких случаев.

Другим вариантом может быть например привязка поведения/логики/слушателя/события к конкретному типу, например:

```
if(user instanceof Friend) { 
     //blah-blah 
}
```

Comment: Имхо, для этого есть интерфейсы.

Comment: Интерфейсы не всегда подходят для этого